# How to make a lineEdit show decimal numbers instead of scientific in Qt

Tags: qt

This is a section of my app which is a calculator in Qt:

```
 QString ss;
QTextStream (&ss) << expression();  // expression() return a double value
result_box -> setText(ss); // result_box is a lineEdit
```

When I type `10^6` and the function `expression()` returns that value, in `result_box` the scientific notation of it will be shown, **1e+06**!

How to do to make the app show the result in decimal, **1000000** rather than that scientific notation?

**The updated part:**

I think I should write a code for it like this:

```
if( d is like an int number)
    result_box -> setText(QString::number(d , 'f', 0));
else if ( d is a double number with n numbers after point)
   result_box -> setText(QString::number(d , 'f', n));
```

Comment: Probably the static [QString::Number()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6) method is the easiest way.

Comment: I used this **ss.number(expression(), 'g', 6);** and then **result_box -> setText(ss);** but this time no result! :(

Comment: @franky `ss.number` will return the string not put it in `ss`. Naturally it's empty

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `'f'` instead of `'g'` since `'g'` takes the most concise format.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#argument-formats

```
QString ss;
QTextStream (&ss) << 1000000.0;
ui->lineEdit->setText( QString::number( ss.toDouble() , 'f') );

.toDouble( &ok ); // if you want to check if the conversion actually worked.
```

Precision is 6 by default, if you want something else you can set it, otherwise no need.

---

So in short:

```
result_box->setText( QString::number( expression( ) , 'f' ) );
```

will do the trick for you.

Comment: I did this **result_box -> setText(QString::number(expression( ) , 'f'));**. If **expression()** returns 1000000, this statement make *result_box* show **1000000.000000** which has many excess zeros! :(

Comment: @franky ofc precision is 6. You can put it on 2 or whatever you want it to be

Comment: I changed the statement to **result_box -> setText(QString::number(expression( ) , 'f', 0));**. It's fine for *int* numbers now, but not for *double* ones! :( :(